# How to connect/sync xAxis crosshairs between multiple HighStocks charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to dynamically sync the xAxis crosshairs across multiple HighStocks charts.

The example http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hh90ps4c/28/ demonstrates how to sync the controls inside one chart. I cloned the demo into this  http://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/ayf5gst2/ ...and replaced the single chart by a table with two charts. The JavaScript code was almost just duplicated for the second chart.

Out of the box, zooming, panning and the rangeSelector sliders in the two charts are nicely synced (I did not change any code to achieve that).

The problem is that the xAxis crosshairs in the two charts are not synced, they work inside each chart individually. How can that be done?

```
/* thanks */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the charts are not in one column, the problem is the mouse event `x` coordinate. You can refer to the first chart in the column to get the coordinates you need:

```
$('#container1').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        // Find coordinates within the chart
        event = Highcharts.charts[0].pointer.normalize(e);
        // Get the hovered point
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true);

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8krwuof9/

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.